# Global variable resets to its initial value

Tags: python

Please don't delete I am just a beginner, I have searched on the forum but I still can not figure out how to solve it.
I am creating a function that adds `1` to variable called `a` if a certain condition is met.
it updates `a` to `1` just one time for a second and it sets `a` to `0` again, despite I have declared `a` as a global variable.
I also tried to assign the function output to `a` but no change happens.
Thank you!

`N` is a value that keeps increasing outside the script. It starts with `0` and increases by `100` (the `Sub` value) each second until it reaches a value of `2000` and starts to count from `0` again . `Sub` = `100` , `Max`=`1500`. The problem is that each time `N` changes the code runs again from the beginning so `a` is set to `0`

```
a=0

def index():
    global a
    if N==Max+Sub:
        a=a+1
    return a

c=index()
```

Comment: If you are expecting `a` to keep its updated value between *runs*, then no, that won't happen. `a = 0` executes each time you run your script. If you want to preserve the incremented value between runs, you need to save the value to a file before exiting and reading the previous file on startup.

Comment: This code works for me: ```>>> a = 0
>>> def index():
...   global a
...   a = a + 1
...   return a
...
>>> index()
1
>>> index()
2
>>> index()
3```  Sorry for the mess. I did not think that this should be an answer but I forgot that multiline code is not showing in the comments.

Comment: N==Max+Sub is true for a second and so c is 1 for a second and goes back to be 0 , sorry I mean I check c , I will edit the question.

Comment: A challenging part of posting here is that you need an example that is runnable and demonstrates the problem. Here, since `N`, `Max` and `Sub` are not defined, we can't run it. But if we do, it won't demontrate the problem. `a` starts out a zero but there is nothing what will set it to zero again. You'd have to run the program a second time to do that .Perhaps you have other code setting `a` to zero later?

Comment: It helps to address comments. chepner is speculating that you are talking about the value of the variable on multiple runs. If that's the case, update your question to clearly state that you want the variable over multiple runs. If not, address a comment to chepner, saying that its just a single run. We guess, you clarify.

Comment: Alright, N is a value that keeps increasing outside the script. It starts with 0 and increases 100 (the Sub value)  each second until it reaches a value of 2000 and starts to count from 0 again . Sub = 100 , Max=1500. The problem is that  each time N changes the code runs again from the beginning so a is set to 0 .

Answer (score 1):

The posted code only calls `index` a single time, and thus only increments it once.  If you run the code again, it does *everything* again, including setting `a` to 0.

If you want to preserve information *across* executions, you need to store it outside of the function, in something like a file or a database.

Comment: Thank you, I will try storing it in file.